# augmented reality - opengl or canvas

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am creating an augmented reality app and i want to draw POIS in the camerasurface. I want to ask one of the [opengl](/questions/tagged/opengl) and [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) is the appropriate for an augmented reality app and which are the benefits of either approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use **augmented reality** plugin jar of **andengine**  [download from here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine)